# how to hide all mat-checkboxes/mat-radio-buttons using *ngIf

Tags: angular

In my quiz app, I need to hide all mat-checkboxes and mat-radio-buttons next to labels using *ngIf statement in Angular. I was using ::ng-deep in my CSS previously, but was told this is not good practice and should be able to hide them using ng-if in the template. Please could you help me. Here's my code so far:

```
<div class="options" *ngFor="let option of currentQuestion.options; index as i">
  <div class="multiple-answer" *ngIf="multipleAnswer">
    <mat-checkbox
      (change)="setSelected(i)"
      [class.is-correct]="option.selected && option.correct"
      [class.is-incorrect]="option.selected && !option.correct">

      <mat-checkbox-label>
        <span>{{ i + 1 }}. {{ option.text }}</span>

        <ng-container *ngIf="option.selected">
          <mat-icon class="feedback-icon"
                    *ngIf="option.correct && isCorrectAnswerSelected">done</mat-icon>
          <mat-icon class="feedback-icon"
                    *ngIf="!option.correct">clear</mat-icon>
        </ng-container>
      </mat-checkbox-label>
    </mat-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comment it is not possible with *ngIf. This is a solution using ViewEncapsulation. Spcifically "ShadowDom".

### What is ShadowDom?

Its basically a "shadow" DOM inside another DOM. The trick is that no styles declared in the parent DOM affect the styles in the shadow DOM. Addidionally, Angular does not encapsulate any CSS so that styles for nested components (like Material Components) can be overridden without ::ng-deep.

### Usage for your situation

In order to activate the shadow DOM insert this into your @Component decorator in the .ts file:

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom <-- this activates the shadow DOM
})
export class AppComponent {
  ...
}
```

Now don't forget that any CSS specified outside has no effect. If you want your Material Components to be styled, you have to import the theme in your .css file explicitly:

app.component.scss

```
// choose your theme, can only be one :)
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css';
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css';
```

and last but not least you can override the display attribute by simply specifying the following in your app.component.scss:

```
div.mat-checkbox-inner-container {
  display: none;
}
```

For icons to work we need to specify the following class in the css file:

```
.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -moz-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

If this does not work add the following:

```
/* fallback */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v55/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it seems to remove the entire mat-checkbox and mat-checkbox-labels along with it from the DOM. Would like to remove just the checkbox.

Comment: Ah I understood it wrong then. Sorry. But I think this is not possible with *ngIf since as you said the label is inside the mat-checkbox. So using CSS is probably the only way to go. If you dont want to use ng-deep (which is indeed bad practise) have a look at [Angular ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation#ShadowDom). Add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` to your @Component in your .ts file. This component is not scoped anymore and your CSS should apply to nested components.

Comment: I've added ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom, not sure what CSS to use to hide the checkboxes. Is using the ShadowDom good practice?

Comment: I changed my solution to use the shadow DOM technique. Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: And yes I would declare it as a better (maybe not best) practice, it is actually well documented on [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) itself. It is definitely better than using ::ng-deep

Comment: Thank you! Yes it does remove the checkboxes/radio-buttons, but now when I select an answer the mat-icons are not displaying and the styling of the messages are not showing up.

Comment: Correct, that' because the CSS class .material-icons is not applied in the shadow DOM. You can specify it in your component again. See my updated anwer. The shadow DOM is not connected to any other css than the styles declared in it. So make sure everyhting is present (.is-correct and .is-incorrect for example).

Comment: Okay, I think I understand, so basically I need to repeat some code from my styles.scss, but I'm using Angular Material icons which are not displaying, but I can switch to Material Design which is better. Thank you.